# Vim, How to create key bindings to: shift, ctrl, alt, cmd keys?

Tags: vim, configuration, key-bindings, neovim

I want to create keybindings like with the keys: shift, ctrl, alt, cmd, but don't know what how to insert them in the configuration file:

like I know that Ctrl is represented as `C`, I could write: `ctrl+p` as `<C-p>`, but how would you write:

`alt+p` ?
`shift+p` ?
`cmd+p` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the help file for `:h shift`. Basically it will lead to:

```
<S-...>  shift-key                      shift <S-
<C-...>  control-key                    control ctrl <C-
<M-...>  alt-key or meta-key            meta alt <M-
<A-...>  same as <M-...>                <A-
<D-...>  command-key (Macintosh only)   <D-
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside Vim, run:  `:help key-notations`

This will give you a list of all the abbreviations (symbols) of different keys that you will use when mapping.

For instance, after running the above command you will find that alt is notated as:  `<M-...>` so for alt+p you would use:  `<M-p>`

Comment: I think it's `:help key-notation` (without the `s`)